# What would "the whole idea was neutral as the mussels had become, harsh and negative as the fresh water" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I encountered the boldfaced expression while reading, and would like to know what it means:

> “After all, I may be rescued today.”
>
> He examined the thought and found that **the whole idea was neutral as
> the mussels had become, harsh and negative as the fresh water**. He
> climbed to the water-hole and crawled in. The red deposit lay in a
> band nearly two inches wide at the nearer edge.

- William Golding, *Pincher Martin*, Chapter 7

I guess the whole idea would mean the thought that he would be rescued today.

And I guess, by "neutral," he would mean that the idea had become devoid of emotion, or, harmless, because he had been sick after eating raw mussels but now recovered. (But my guess could be wrong.)

But I have no idea as to how it became "harsh and negative" as the fresh water, and wanted to ask your opinion.

Comment: You do know that he doesn't get rescued, don't you? We have explained a number of times now that the language used in this section is not intended to be taken literally, and you have not responded to that.

Comment: This is literary criticism rather than an English language question. Only Golding could tell you exactly what he meant.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Thank you for the comment. Yes, I do know the plot. I just didn't say that it might be a spolier... But probably this is not a language question as you suggest.